# BDD precondition volatility

Tags: automated-testing, bdd

If there are some possible points of failure in your preconditions, is it a bad practice to put in asserts in your Given steps, or if that is unclear, should Given statements ever fail?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to explain what you mean by "volatility in setting up preconditions"? Do you mean that something in the setup steps fails so you don't get to your test, or that the setup steps can have different outcomes?

Comment: "the setup steps can have different outcomes?" <-- exactly.  Thank you.  You said it much better than me.  Cheers!

Comment: If the setup steps can have different (valid) outcomes, then they should not be part of your setup steps. They should be part of separate tests.

Answer (score 1):

Each test case should have a specific objective that is closely dependent on 
 preconditions.

In order to accurately assert that the test has passed i would recommend including the precondition as a assertion. Failure would indicate that the setup failed, not that the functionality failed.
Additional if you need to test how the functionality behaves when a precondition is missing, create a separate test.